# Parsing JSON file python

Tags: python, json

whole file is here:https://1drv.ms/u/s!AizscpxS0QM4hJpFPnbeAexYPwYu9Q

I want from this part:

```
"subtasks": [
                    {
                        "fields": {
                            "issuetype": {
                                "avatarId": 10316,
                                "description": "The sub-task of the issue",
                                "iconUrl": "https://jira.corp.company.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10316&avatarType=issuetype",
                                "id": "10101",
                                "name": "Sub-task",
                                "self": "https://jira.corp.company.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/10101",
                                "subtask": true
                            },
                            "priority": {
                                "iconUrl": "https://jira.corp.company.com/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg",
                                "id": "3",
                                "name": "Medium",
                                "self": "https://jira.corp.company.com/rest/api/2/priority/3"
                            },
                            "status": {
                                "description": "",
                                "iconUrl": "https://jira.corp.company.com/",
                                "id": "10000",
                                "name": "Backlog",
                                "self": "https://jira.corp.company.com/rest/api/2/status/10000",
                                "statusCategory": {
                                    "colorName": "blue-gray",
                                    "id": 2,
                                    "key": "new",
                                    "name": "To Do",
                                    "self": "https://jira.corp.company.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2"
                                }
                            },
                            "summary": "Remove user account in Local AD"
                            },
```

to extract `"Remove user account in Local AD"` (summary field)

So far i have this code:

```
data = json.load(open(1.json))


for issue in data['issues']:
   print issue['fields']['subtasks']
```

and getting section above, how to get only summary value ?

if i add:

```
for issue in data['issues']:
   print issue['fields']['subtasks']['summary']
```

i get:

```
 print issue['fields']['subtasks']['summary']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

same with:

```
    for i in range (0, len (data['issues'])):
       print data['issues']['fields']['subtasks'][i]['fields']['summary']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Subtasks is a list, loop through it and print `item['summary']` for each item in the list. Although from this example it looks like it would be `item['fields']['summary']`

Comment: `item['fields']['summary']` gives summary of main issues, not subtasks summary (Remove user account in Local AD)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, subtasks is the key, but the item is a list!

So it will be `issue['fields']['subtasks'][0]['summary']` what you are looking for.

Comment: `print issue['fields']['subtasks'][0]['summary']
KeyError: 'summary'`

Comment: I had a closer look: try `print issue['fields']['subtasks'][0]['fields']['summary']`
It should work

Comment: already tried that:  `print issue['fields']['subtasks'][0]['fields']['summary']
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I think is better using the method .get()  issue.get('fields').get(...)

Comment: `print issue.get("fields").get("subtasks").get("summary")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @nawarkhede

```
for issue in data['issues']:
  for subtask in issue['fields']['subtasks']:
    if subtask['fields']['summary'] == 'The specified directory could not be found in the specified region.-traider':
      print subtask['fields']['summary']
```